# How to make text effects?

Tags: text

[image]

How to make the white contour, the red shadow, the lines inside the text and it seems that there is like a "shadow line" inside the text as well. It seems that the person who design this t-shirt took these letters from a font and modify them and thats what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you're trying to create, what you've tried so far, and what about it is not working? As it is your question is not clear enough for us to help you well. You can edit your question to add the necessary information. Welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: Mentioning the software you want to use might help.

Comment: "you draw them". Sorry, this question is simply too broad.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the inner straight lines are made with the Pattern Overlay Blending Option that you can find by double clicking on a Photoshop layer. First of all, you need to find a pattern that matches what you want to do on Google and then load it in Photoshop, or [create one yourself](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/creating-custom-pattern-in-photoshop/).

For the inner drop lines that we can barely see, it seems like it has been done by hand while designing the Typeface but you can create such elements by using the [pen tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSdov7nVYdo), a very accurate feature. You'll be able to create lines that will look the same!

For the multiple strokes, you can duplicate the text layer, moving it right and down and change the color. It will create gaps at the letters corners so you either fill the gaps on a new layer or on the same layer after right clicking on the layer and selecting "Raterize Layer".

Once you are happy with your strokes, in order to make the thin green stroke that is not shifted around all the effects: Select all your layers, right click and select "Create a group". Once you have the folder icon in your Layer pannel, double click on it and simply apply a stroke with the blending options.

For the very subtle shadows made by the fold of the shirt, if you want to do that in Photoshop you can use simple black color brush with low hardness on a separate layer and then use a Clipping mask.

Comment: Your English is good! Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign!

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop Styles:

1. [Stroke](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=photoshop%20styles%20stroke) to create the white contour.
2. [Drop shadow](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=photoshop%20styles%20shadow) to create the shadow.

To modify a font, you can use [a bunch of tools](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=free%20font%20editors).

Or you can just take the letters you want and vectorize them in Illustrator.

-- Edited --

To create the line hatches, you can use [another photoshop style](https://www.google.com/search?q=line%20hatches%20styles%20photoshop&espv=2&biw=1228&bih=801&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=qjfXVKWkGoyxogSHuILQDw&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAA&dpr=2).

Comment: what about the black lines running in the text? And the line on left side of the text, like a "shadow line" of the contour of the letter, don't know if you can see it?

Comment: It's like a "drop shadow line" inside of the text, how do you do that?

Comment: Thanks for contributing! Let us know if you have any questions and welcome to GraphicDesign!